# Old data gets wiped from POST when I use GET

Tags: php, html

So I am having an issue.  I used POST to send data to a new page.  I use get to send data to a function but it seems the POST data get wiped.  Here some code to help explain.

POST CODE to send to form vieworder (works perfect!)

```
<form method="post" action="vieworder.php">
     <input type="hidden" name ="user_id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>">
     <input type="hidden" name ="id" value="<?php echo $data1[$x]['id']; ?>">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="View"> </td>
</form>
```

So on the vieworder page I want used to be able to update the data using this form.
This form works as well except i need that value "id" from the orginal post.  It works and the "id"has the data until I use this form.

```
<form name="approveform" method="get" action="">
            Index Number*: <input type="text" name="IndexNum">&nbsp;
            <input type="submit" value="Approve" action="">
</form>
```

I would also prefer to use the POST method but using GET was my first solution to no deleting the data from POST.

Anyways I then just send the data to a function to update two fields.

Any way to get correct the code?

Comment: on vieworder, in the form add a hidden elements and populate it with the data posted. - or start using sessions

Comment: Every time you submit a form both `$_GET[]` and `$_POST[]` are populated with new data - any old data is lost. You'll need to store any data you want to persist in `$_SESSION[]`, or add it as a hidden element to your second form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  $id=$_POST['user_id'];
?>

<form name="approveform" method="get" action="">
  Index Number*: <input type="text" name="IndexNum">&nbsp;
  <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $id;?>'>
  <input type="submit" value="Approve" action="">
</form>
```

Comment: OO so simple yet so smart!  Thanks!

Comment: This code is vulnerable to various types of injection, since you're printing the contents of a user submitted variable directly into your HTML. This is quite insecure.

Comment: Agree with JAL. Stick with the $_SESSION. You are already using it. No need to embed it into <input> since $_SESSION will be visible through all your pages until you close the browser or destroy it.

Comment: The code did not work.  I cannot enter php inside the value part of the form.  Ill read up on the $_SESSION...

Comment: Why can't you? Make sure you use .php extension on your approveform file. Can you post your code?

Comment: Hmm I have PHP everywhere else in the file it just wont let me enter php inside that value part....

Comment: Fixed it need a space :)